# Super-sized background button rollover area

Tags: css, button, background

I have no problem with

rollovers on navbars... But what if the rollover-backgrounds are varied and of varied size? I can't seem to set the size of the li block. I see the image in the button but it's a small portion of it. I guess I could devolve to doing straight-up image rollovers but I'd prefer to do it properly.

Thanks

Comment: what have you got so far? If we see what you have already tried we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I agree with @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose, can you show an example please.

Comment: I apologize gentlemen... I had a family emergency... and then I figured it out... I will post it here later. I wish I could do it more efficiently in the CSS. Thank you for your time.